# Why do I get `RepositoryNotFoundError` error in NestJS-TypeORM app?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Okay so I'm using `TYPEORM_` prefixed environment variables to register `TypeOrmModule` into my app. Then I'm loading entities using `.forFeature()` like so:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Foo])],
  controllers: [FooController],
  providers: [FooService],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})
export class FooModule {}
```

No matter whether I use `forRoot()` or `forRoot({ autoLoadEntities: true })` in `AppModule`, I get `RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "Foo" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?` error while working with the dev server. Any idea what's going on? My service looks like:

```js
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Foo) private readonly fooRepository: Repository<Foo>) {}
}
```

I tried the followings as single and/or combined, still didn't solve the issue.

- Put a name in `@Entity()` decorator.

```js
@Entity('foo')
export class Foo {}
```

- Try `forRootAsync()`.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () =>
        Object.assign(await getConnectionOptions(), { autoLoadEntities: true }),
    }),
    FooModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

- Pass `'default'` to `forFeature()`.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Foo], 'default')],
  controllers: [FooController],
  providers: [FooService],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})
export class FooModule {}
```

- Try using `entities` key in `forRoot()`.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({ entities: [Foo] }),
    FooModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to define connectionName inside `getConnectionOptions`

example:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () =>
        Object.assign(await getConnectionOptions('default'), { autoLoadEntities: true }),
    }),
    FooModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```